# project.exe has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++, list, visual-c++, linked-list, circular-list

I had a circular link list which has add, delete, printlist and search functions etc. All the functions works correctly but when I delete all nodes in the list and than try to add new nodes to the same list, I get project.exe has triggered a breakpoint message.

List.h

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

using namespace std;

class list {
public:

    struct node {       
        string data, assignee, date;
        node *next;
    };

    typedef struct node NodePtr;

    NodePtr *head, *current, *temp, *dummy;

    list();
    void add();
    void del();
    void printList();
    void menu();
    void exit();
    void search();

};

#endif
```

Source.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"
#include<string>

using namespace std;

list::list() {          //constructor
    head = NULL;
    current = NULL;
    temp = NULL;    
}
void list::add(){
    string addTask, addAssignee, addDate;
    NodePtr *newNode = new NodePtr;

    //entering the data of the tasks
    cout << "Enter the name of the task:\n"<<"<<";
    getline(cin, addTask);          // compailer doesnt detect the first getline   function, ı dont understan why. ı had to put it twice
    getline(cin, addTask);
    cout << "Enter the assignee name for the task:\n" << "<<";
    getline(cin, addAssignee);
    cout << "Enter the deadline for the task:\n" << "<<";
    getline(cin, addDate);
    cout << "\n";

    //assignt data to the new node
    newNode->data = addTask;
    newNode->assignee = addAssignee;
    newNode->date = addDate;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (head != NULL){

        current = head;

        while (current->next != head){          //finding the last node
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = newNode;
        dummy = newNode;
        dummy->next = head;             //  we make the list, circular
    }
    else               //here will work if the list is empty
    {
        head = newNode;
        dummy = newNode;
        head->next=head;
    }


}
void list::printList(){
    int i = 1;
    current = head;
    if (head == NULL){
        cout << "List is empty\n\n";
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            cout << i << "-";
            cout << current->data << endl;
            cout << current->assignee << endl;
            cout << current->date << endl << endl;
            current = current->next;
            i++;
        } while (current != dummy->next);
    }
}

void list::del(){                       //tüm liste silindikten sonra tekrar işlem(ekleme, listeleme etc.) yapılamıyor hata veriyor
    NodePtr *delPtr;
    delPtr = NULL;
    int ID;
    cout << "These tasks exist in the list:\n";
    printList();
    cout << "Choose the ID of the task you want to remove:\n";
    cin >> ID;
    if (head == NULL){
        cout << "List does not includes any task.\n";
    }
    else
    if (ID == 1){
        delPtr = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete delPtr;
        dummy->next = head;
    }
    else
    {
        current = head;

        for (int k = 1; k <= ID - 1; k++){
            temp = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
        if (current == dummy){
            dummy = temp;
            dummy->next = head;
        }
        delPtr = current;
        current = current->next;
        temp->next = current;

        delete delPtr;
    }
}
void list::menu(){

    cout << "Choose an operation\n"
        << "A: Add Task\n"
        << "S: Search for Task\n"
        << "L: List All Tasks\n"
        << "R: Remove Task\n"
        << "E: Exit\n\n"<<"<<";

}

void list::search(){
    string searchTask;
    NodePtr *search;
    search = head;

    cout << "To search for a task, enter its task name or assignee name:\n" << "<<";
    getline(cin, searchTask);
    getline(cin, searchTask);

    while (search != dummy){//bu satır problemli gibi gözüküyor

        if (search->data == searchTask || search->assignee == searchTask){
            cout << search->data << endl
                << search->assignee << endl
                << search->date << endl<<endl;
        }
        search = search->next;
    }

}

void list::exit(){
    node *delPtr;
    current = head;
    if (head != NULL){

        do{
            temp = current;
            delPtr = temp;
            current = current->next;

            delete delPtr;
        } while (current != dummy);
    }
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main(){


    char operation;
    list tasks;
    tasks.menu();


    cin >> operation;

    while (operation!='E' && operation!='e'){

        switch (operation)
        {
        case 'A':case'a':
            tasks.add();
            break;
        case 'S': case's':
            tasks.search();
            break;
        case 'L': case 'l': 
            cout << "All tasks are listed below:\n";
            tasks.printList();
            break;
        case 'R': case 'r':
            tasks.del();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        tasks.menu();
        cin >> operation;



    }

    tasks.exit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, have you just triggered a breakpoint?

Comment: That's a kit if code. Does the debugger tell you which line?

Comment: At a glance, I would suspect that your `del()` function doesn't correctly set the list's pointers after deleting the last element. I'd suggest using a debugger and inspecting the list's state after the last delete.